# gstreamer plugin to get video packets and meta data from transport stream

Tags: c, gstreamer

hi i am trying to demux transport stream file in to seperate video and audio files(only Ts packets)  using gstreamer plugins,i tried the following command line options

for video

```
    gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=~/Desktop/TS_ES/katy.ts ! tsdemux !  filesink location = abc.mpg
```

for audio

```
    gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=~/Desktop/TS_ES/katy.ts ! tsdemux ! mpegaudioparse ! filesink location = abc.mp3
```

....but i am getting only Elementary streams ,not transport streams ,does any 
one had idea to demux(Extract) Audio/Video packets from Transport Stream ,and

one more question is which plugin is useful to extract metadata(PAT/PMT...) 
from transport stream

Comment: A transport stream demuxer will always give you demuxed elementary streams that are a part of the program that you want to demux. If you want to extract raw packets or PSI data, have a look at DVBinspector or dvbsnoop, not GStreamer.

Comment: hi Daniel,thanks for your quick response ,Gstreamer didn't had any plugins to extracts Rawpackets ? or better to go for DVBInspector

Comment: GStreamer is a media streaming framework and as such isn't really interested in raw packets. That isn't to say that a "raw TS packet" plugin doesn't exist, but I strongly suggest you try DVBinspector or dvbsnoop instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is transport stream, or elementary stream. But if you what the direction of extract raw data, AppSink is your best choice.

```
GstMapFlags flags;
GstMapInfo info;
guint64 i, count;

flags = GST_MAP_READ | GST_MAP_WRITE;
if(! gst_buffer_map(buf, &info, flags)) {
    g_print("buffer map failed\n");
    return 0;
}
// *(info->data) pointing to the first byte of raw data
gst_buffer_unmap(buf, &info);
```

video meta is something i am working on. If anyone have anything, please share it with me.